# set iOS bg images all screen sizes

Tags: ios

I have created background images for all iOS devices. As far as I understand, iOS will pick the appropriate image at runtime according to screen resolutions.

Is there a way to set the image as a screen background for the root view? The method should take automatic image picking into account.

Comment: When you say root view, can you clarify? Do you mean the root view of the default UIWindow created? Or the loading screen that gets shown?
Either way, the way to do it would be to just add a UIImageView and set it to the same height and width, or use this (which seems ugly): https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/initWithPatternImage:

Comment: Is there a way to use the story board?

Comment: I come from an Android background. With Android, you just set the image to the background and that's it. The system will pick the correct image.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to set the image as a screen background for the root view

In the storyboard, locate the scene representing the root view controller and its view. Drag a UIImageView into the main view and pin its top, left, bottom, and right to the edges of its superview with a `constant` of zero. Send it to the back so that it's behind all other subviews of the main view. Set its image to the desired image, and supply an appropriate content mode. Done.